# Network problem of visualization of vertex

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have a question about visualization of
network in *Mathematica*:

for example: for this network

```
g = ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph", "Friendship"}];
```

when we calculate `ClosenessCentrality[g]` and visualize with

```
HighlightGraph[g, VertexList[g], VertexSize -> Thread[VertexList[g] -> Rescale[%]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We can not see the vertex of James. Why? The value exists and is positive.

Comment: Try removing `Rescale`, as this will set the minimum of the list to `0`, i.e. `HighlightGraph[g, VertexList[g], 
 VertexSize -> Thread[VertexList[g] -> ClosenessCentrality[g]]]`

Comment: Exactly!!! thank you for this fast response!

Comment: But we can not see the weight clearly?

Comment: See the documentation of `Rescale` for other parameters on how to rescale the output of `ClosenessCentrality[g]`, e.g. `Rescale[ClosenessCentrality[g], {0, 1}, {0.01, 1}]` or any other transform (e.g. simply `HighlightGraph[g, VertexList[g], 
 VertexSize -> 
  Thread[VertexList[g] -> 0.1 + Rescale[ClosenessCentrality[g]]]]`
), whatever you desire! Not knowing what you actually want to achieve leaves me guessing

Comment: I do it I understand Pinguin Dirk thank you!

Comment: a bug in the [Help system](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1G8rw.png)?

Comment: @cormullion Do you think it's a bug?

Comment: @Sjoerd I'm not sure really - it depends on how big James' circle should be. My eyesight couldn't see any red at all, but I think there is a reddish pixel there...

Comment: @cormullion I suppose it should be size 0, which boils down to the tiniest speck possible. Actually, I don't see any red at all.